# previous custom element overwrited by next elements when import serval webcomponent

Tags: javascript, web, web-component

when multiple custom element in a single page, why always show the last element and the previous element is overwrited. for example:

**first component:**

```html
<template id="cmpt-1">
  webcomponent 1
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var thatDoc = document;
  var thisDoc = (thatDoc._currentScript || thatDoc.currentScript).ownerDocument;
  var t = thisDoc.querySelector('#cmpt-1');

  var protos = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {
      value: function() {
        var clone = thatDoc.importNode(t.content, true);
        this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
      }
    }
  });
  thatDoc.registerElement('cmpt-1', {
    prototype: protos
  }); 
</script>
```

**second component:**

```html
<template id="cmpt-2">
  webcomponent 2
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var thatDoc = document;
  var thisDoc = (thatDoc._currentScript || thatDoc.currentScript).ownerDocument;
  var t = thisDoc.querySelector('#cmpt-2');

  var protos = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {
      value: function() {
        var clone = thatDoc.importNode(t.content, true);
        this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
      }
    }
  });
  thatDoc.registerElement('cmpt-2', {
    prototype: protos
  }); 
</script>
```

when import these two component in single page,such as that:

**import above component**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="import" href="cmpt1.html">
  <link rel="import" href="cmpt2.html">
</head>

<body>
  <cmpt-1></cmpt-1>
  <cmpt-2></cmpt-2>
</body>

</html>
```

then only show "component 2", the second element overwrite the first element .

Comment: you should use Code Samples instead of Snippets if there's nothing to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping codes in the script tag in a immediately invoked function expression to confine scopes solves your problem.

```html
<template id="cmpt-2">
    webcomponent 2
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var thatDoc = document;
        var thisDoc = (thatDoc._currentScript || thatDoc.currentScript).ownerDocument;
        var t = thisDoc.querySelector('#cmpt-2');

        var protos = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
            createdCallback: {
                value: function() {
                    var clone = thatDoc.importNode(t.content, true);
                    this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
                }
            }
        });
        thatDoc.registerElement('cmpt-2', {
            prototype: protos
        });
    })();

</script>
```

It is the same for 'cmpt-1'.

Answer (score 1):

You define all variables in the global scope - twice, in effect `protos` is a pointer to the second component by the time the components are rendered. The quickfix would be to rename each `protos` to something sensible like `cmpt1` and `cmpt2`, and reference the correct var in `thatDoc.registerElement`. A better solution is to create a generic function that initialized a custom component and avoid the global scope altogether.